# Open all files in folder python

Tags: python

I have this function that is supposed to open all text files in a folder and remove all the "\n" in it.

```
def FormatTXT():

    conhecimentos = os.listdir('U:/AutoCTE/Conhecimentos')

    for x in conhecimentos:
        with open(x, "r+") as f:
            old = f.read()
            text = old.replace("\n", "")
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate(0)
            f.write(text)
            f.close()
```

But this function is returning the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20200119-170415-Conhecimento de Transporte.txt'
```

Happens that this file actually exists in the directory and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: The file paths that you `open` in `x` are missing the prefix `U:/AutoCTE/Conhecimentos`. And since you are in a different directory, those relative paths will not work

Comment: Please post this as an answer, I can't believe I was this dumb hahaha, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file paths that you `open` in `x` are missing the prefix `U:/AutoCTE/Conhecimentos`. And since you are in a different directory, those relative paths will not work

```
def FormatTXT():

    conhecimentos = os.listdir('U:/AutoCTE/Conhecimentos')

    for x in conhecimentos:
        with open('U:/AutoCTE/Conhecimentos/' + x, "r+") as f:
            old = f.read()
            text = old.replace("\n", "")
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate(0)
            f.write(text)
            f.close()
```

There are better ways to do this. For example with the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module

Comment: what is the purpose of closing the file if you are using `with`?

Comment: There is not a purpose, he probably just copied code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem you have is that you forgive to notice that os.listdir() return the name of the file in a directory not their path, you have to append the file name to the dir path using os.path.join()

There are several way to do this I will pick the 3 I use.

first let write a function that remove parse the file text because you get it right
, I would just recommend caution using read() in case of very large file.

```
def remove_end_lines(file_): 
    """
    remove "\n" from file
    """
    with open(file_, "r+") as f:
        old = f.read()
        text = old.replace("\n", "")
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate(0)
        f.write(text)
```

now we have to tackle your main problem file path.
 ->  a choice could be to change the working dir (you should first register the original working dir in order to be able to go back to it)

```
def FormatTXT(my_dir):

    original_dir = os.getcwd() # register original working dir
    conhecimentos = os.listdir(my_dir) # liste file in the dir
    os.chdir(my_dir)  # change dir

    for file_ in conhecimentos: 
        remove_end_lines(file_)

    os.chdir(original_dir) # go back to original dir
```

second choice let's use  os.path.join()

```
def FormatTXT(my_dir):

    conhecimentos = os.listdir(my_dir) # liste all files in the dir

    for file_ in conhecimentos: 
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_)  # create the file path by appening the file name to the directory path
        remove_end_lines(file_path)
```

In case you have subdirectory and want to perform the same operation you should use os.walk()

```
def FormatTXT(my_dir):
    for dir_path, dir_name, files_name in os.walk(my_dir):
    # files_name is a list of all file in dir_path,
        if files_name:  # if there is file in the current dir (the list is not empty)

        for file_ in files_names:
            file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_)  
            remove_end_lines(file_path)
```

I hope this help.
if you have more question don't hesitate to ask